# Getting Error while starting milvus_cli on Centos7 (dlopen: /usr/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found)

Tags: command-line-interface, milvus

Getting below error while running milvus-cli on Centos7

```
./milvus_cli-v0.2.0-beta.2-Linux 

[1476] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIF9oMNS/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /usr/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIF9oMNS/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

when we run ./milvus_cli-v0.2.0-beta.2-Linux, it should connect us to milvus_cli prompt.

Required python version is already installed and available under /usr/local/bin/python3.11.